# How to get value of <a name=""> in JSP

Tags: html, jsp

So i have this html

```
<tr>
   <%
   ArrayList<Project> projects = (ArrayList<Project>)session.getAttribute("projects");
   for(Project p: projects) {
   %>
   <td>
   <a href="GoToProjectPage" name="projecttitle">
      <%=p.getProjectTitle()%>
   </a>
   </td>
</tr>
```

however, i do not know how to get the "projecttitle" in the a href. I tried using the code below but it does not work. we are required to use MVC

`request.getParameter("projecttitle")`

Comment: yes, the first set of code is in jsp

Comment: i think you are mistaken this by <input>

Comment: I am trying to insert a link/servlet inside a <table> that will lead to another jsp depending on the value of the p.getProjectTitle()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the parameter to the `href` of the `<a>` element:

```
<a href="GoToProjectPage?projecttitle=<%=p.getProjectTitle()%>">
    <%=p.getProjectTitle()%>
</a>
```

Comment: @user3336958 Glad to hear it. I've edited the answer to remove the `name` attribute because it's meaningless; `<a>` elements don't have `name` attributes.